# Collecting data from list and then removing

Tags: c#

I created this sample and wanted any advice on how to make this code; cleaner, more effective, just overall better! I am collecting the days data from the NegativeScheduleSentence model and  ScheduleSentencePart model and removing the model from the concepts object. only to have to re-add them back in using the days object from both models. Any help would be great.

sample working
https://dotnetfiddle.net/5jA7xh

```cs
if (concepts.NegativeScheduleSentencePartModel.Count() > 0 &&
    concepts.ScheduleSentencePartModel.Count() > 0)
{
    var conceptsNegativeScheduleCalendarDays = 
        concepts.NegativeScheduleSentencePartModel.Select(x => x.Days).ToList();
    var PositiveandNegativeDays = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < conceptsNegativeScheduleCalendarDays.Count; i++)
    {                   
        foreach (int day in conceptsNegativeScheduleCalendarDays[i])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(day);
            PositiveandNegativeDays.Add(day);
        }
    }

    var conceptscheduleCalendarDays = concepts.ScheduleSentencePartModel
        .Select(x => x.Days).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < conceptscheduleCalendarDays.Count; i++)
    {
        foreach (int day in conceptscheduleCalendarDays[i])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(day);
            PositiveandNegativeDays.Add(day);
        }
    }

    concepts.ScheduleSentencePartModel
        .RemoveRange(0, ScheduleSentencePartModel.Count);
    concepts.NegativeScheduleSentencePartModel
        .RemoveRange(0, conceptsNegativeScheduleCalendarDays.Count);

    var PositiveandNegativeScheduleSentencePartModel = 
        new List<ScheduleSentencePartModel>();
    ScheduleSentencePartModel.Add(
        new ScheduleSentencePartModel() { 
            Days = PositiveandNegativeDays, Isvalid = true });
    concepts.ScheduleSentencePartModel = ScheduleSentencePartModel;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Type names should be written in PascalCase (`class Concepts`). Variables should be written in camelCase (`negativeScheduleSentence`).
- All the public fields should be properties (PascalCase).
- `concepts.NegativeScheduleSentencePartModel` and `concepts.ScheduleSentencePartModel` are lists (`List<T>`). Lists have a `Count` property. No need to call the LINQ `Count()` extension method. Write `concepts.NegativeScheduleSentencePartModel.Count > 0`.
- `NegativeScheduleSentencePartModel` and `ScheduleSentencePartModel` are identical. From a conceptual point of view, it can sometimes make sense to have two types, because they could evolve differently in future, but then they should have a common (abstract) base class (e.g., `ScheduleSentencePartModelBase`) or implement the same interface. This allows you to treat them the same way. E.g., you could have a method `void PrintScheduleSentence(ScheduleSentencePartModelBase scheduleSentence)` that can print both models. However, in your example code I see no reason to have two types.
- You declare and initialize an unused list `PositiveandNegativeScheduleSentencePartModel`. Remove it unless it is used in your real code.
- Instead of `someList.RemoveRange(0, someList.Count);` you can write `someList.Clear();`.
- Classes are reference types. This means that `concepts.ScheduleSentencePartModel` and the variable `scheduleSentencePartModel` (changed to camelCase) point to the same list object. It makes no sense to re-assign the variable (last line in the code above).

It is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve with this code, but if its purpose is simply to concatenate all the days from all the lists, this can be achieved much easier. The LINQ extension method `SelectMany` flattens nested collections.

It still makes sense to clear the lists, because you are potentially replacing many ScheduleSentencePartModels by one containing all the days of all the models (if this was your intention, after all it is what your loops do).

```cs
if (concepts.NegativeScheduleSentencePartModel.Count > 0 &&
    concepts.ScheduleSentencePartModel.Count > 0) {

    var positiveandNegativeDays = concepts.NegativeScheduleSentencePartModel
        .SelectMany(x => x.Days)
        .Concat(
            concepts.ScheduleSentencePartModel
            .SelectMany(x => x.Days)
        )
        .OrderBy(d => d) // Optionally sort the days.
        .ToList();

    concepts.NegativeScheduleSentencePartModel.Clear();
    concepts.ScheduleSentencePartModel.Clear();

    concepts.ScheduleSentencePartModel.Add(
        new ScheduleSentencePartModel {
            Days = positiveandNegativeDays, IsValid = true 
        });
}
```

Is the surrounding if-statement necessary? If the lists are empty the code would still work as expected. The only effect it has is to collect the data only when both lists have entries. If only one of the two lists has entries, nothing happens. Was this intended?

- A possible problem is that you select all the entries, even those with `IsValid = false` and replace them by an entry with with `IsValid = true`. Maybe you should exclude the invalid ones.

```cs
var positiveandNegativeDays = concepts.NegativeScheduleSentencePartModel
    .Where(x => x.IsValid)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Days)
    .Concat(
        concepts.ScheduleSentencePartModel
            .Where(x => x.IsValid)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Days)
        )
    .OrderBy(d => d)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks I was thinking that I only needed to do this logic if both models have data. If only one of the model has data I dont need to clear and then re-add

Comment: Note that if `concepts.ScheduleSentencePartModel` has more than one `ScheduleSentencePartModel` then it will be replaced by a single one having the days of all of them plus the ones from all the `NegativeScheduleSentencePartModel`s in `concepts.NegativeScheduleSentencePartModel`. So you are not just clearing one and re-adding one but potentially removing many and re-adding one.